# glib-2.0 removed, need them back

Tags: glib

I earlier installed glib-2.42 which was needed as a dependency for a program. But some softwares(sublime text) stopped working and were showing error related to glib. So i downgraded the version to 2.28. Now sublime worked fine with 2.28 but then occurred a conflict between 2.42 and 2.28 version which showed the error:

```
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.28.8, but GLIB (2.42.1)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: Cannot find GLIB: Is pkg-config in your path?
```

THIS i am trying to solve for days and couldn't really find a solution(have tried everything suggested on the forum).

SO NOW, i without realizing, deleted all glib-2.0 files from/usr/include and /usr/share thinking to reinstall glib2.28 back from source thinking that i would get those files back.

But it didnt happen and now i cannot run anything(pidgin, sublime, libreoffice..) and i get the error:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Can i get all the files back? Its urgent. I have already done `apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev`

**EDIT** : and when i install `gsettings-desktop-schemas`, it shows 
`gsettings-desktop-schemas is already the newest version.`

Comment: **How** did you install glib-2.42 and to where (/usr or /usr/local)? How did you "downgrade the version to 2.28"? Have you tried an `apt-get install --reinstall` of the relevant packages?

Comment: It was installed from source. I just did the `make uninstall` of 2.42 and then installed 2.28 over it. then modified the paths.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. I found the solution. Was going to answer it myself after a while. 
Recent glib versions doesn't have all the compilation schemas in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`. So i just copied them from somewhere else. Although i guess they are available in only some of the older glib versions.

Comment: @awhitesong Can you post the complete answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Mandx Actually my main aim was to downgrade glib-2.42 to 2.28 and get it working properly in the system. During the whole procedure i came to this glitch.  So what case you need the solution for ? Just this specific problem or the whole downgrading process, which i believe although worked still shouldn't be followed as a recommended procedure since i manually deleted some files?
As for this specific problem, i just searched online and added all the schemas required, in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` since they got removed when i deleted my glib folders unknowingly. Thanks.

Comment: @awhitesong Actually my problem had nothing to do with GLib, it was just [a problem with the Fish shell and some custom init scripts](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2198). In the end, my problem simply was the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable having a malformed value.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Jammy, `glib-2.0` is in `libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev`